# Propel 1.5 How to make join with OR condition

Tags: join, propel

I need to generate such SQL using Propel build criteria:

```
"SELECT * 
FROM  `table1` 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON ( table1.OBJECT_ID = table2.ID ) 
LEFT JOIN table3 ON ( table1.OBJECT_ID = table3.ID ) 
LEFT JOIN table4 ON ( table4.USER_ID = table2.ID
OR table4.USER_ID = table3.AUTHOR_ID )"
```

Is it possible to make join with or condition? Or maybe some other ways?
Propel 1.5

Answer (score 2):

```
Table1Query::create()
  ->leftJoinTable2()
  ->leftJoinTable3()
  ->useTable2Query()
    ->leftJoinTable4()
  ->endUse()
  ->condition('cond1', Table4::USER_ID . ' = ' . Table2::ID)
  ->condition('cond2', Table4::USER_ID . ' = ' . Table3::AUTHOR_ID)
  ->combine(array('cond1', 'cond2'), Criteria::LOGICAL_OR, 'onClause')
  ->setJoinCondition('Table4', 'onClause')
  ->find();
```

`useTable2Query()` is necessary because your information seems to imply that `Table4` is related to `Table2` and not to `Table1`, and so joining `Table4` directly to `Table1` will result in a series of fatal Propel errors. The "use" functionality bridges that relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The first two joins (table2, table3) are easy, if I recall correctly. Just make table1.OBJECT_ID non-required in your schema, and the left join will be used automatically.

Not immediately sure about the OR join. If you get stuck, one way to do it is to use the above in a raw query, and then "hydrate" objects from the resultset. Another way (very good for complex queries that are a pain to express in an ORM) is to create a database view for the above, and then add a new table in your schema for the view. It's cheating a bit for sure, but for some really complex master-detail things I did in a large symfony project, it was great - and it made query debugging really easy as well.

Comment: @AFriend: I've approved three of your edits just now - they were quite good, given that they were retaliatory. I am in the habit of having to reject such edits as usually being of poor quality. However - be aware that since your rep is under 2K, your edits will go into the review queue and will need to be seen by reviewers. **It is not fair to waste their time because you are angry at me**.

Comment: Please note that I speak from experience. I am a dedicated editor here, and I edit because I care about this site and the community around it. I do not edit anyone's material in order to spite them - I edit material in order to make it more readable, and to help post author understand what a good post looks like.

Comment: I 100% agree, I'm also trying to make this site a better place for people - that's always been my goal since I started an account on here. As you said yourself, you approved my edits so I didn't waste edit-reviewers time.

Comment: @AFriend: not this time, no - but I remain concerned about your motivation, since you do not choose my account my chance. If you are on board with quality and decency as primary goals, then great - we would be in agreement!